# customize underline in action bar sherlock android

Tags: android

I am using android action bar sherlock in my app.
i want my action bar to look ike this.

[image]

But when i change th background color of action bar tab the under line goes away.

here is my code.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<!-- define text style for tabs -->
<item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>

<item name = "actionBarStyle">@style/MyBarStyle</item>
<item name = "android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyBarStyle</item>

<item name = "actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
<item name = "android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>

<item name = "actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyTabBarStyle</item>
<item name = "android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyTabBarStyle</item>


</style>

    <style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" >
<item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text_indicator</item>
<item name= "android:textSize">15dp</item>
<item name= "android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

    <style name="MyBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar" >
   <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
   <item name="android:background">#669933</item>
    <item name="background">#669933</item>
    </style>
   
    <style name="MyTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView" >
   <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="background">#ffffff</item> 
    </style>
   
    <style name="MyTabBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar" >
     <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
   </style>
```

and the output is

[image]

so,just don't know how to set the underline in my action tab.please help..
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for tabnavigation like GooglePlayStore app then `PagerTabStrip` and `ViewPager` would be easy.

Here is good example for you [AndroidSolution4U](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/tabnvigation-like-google-play-store-app.html)

In this tutorial you can customize tab by changing color in following code

```
 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#676966"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#6CBD57" />
```

Comment: please have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html